# New line didnt work in php even with double quotes and PHP_EOL

Tags: php, newline, double-quotes, eol

I dont know why new line didnt work with both double quotes and PHP_EOL.

```
<?php

echo "next line check\n";
echo "next line check1\n";
echo "next line check2" . PHP_EOL;
echo "next line check3";

?>
```

Above is my script. Below is the output i am getting.

```
next line check next line check1 next line check2 next line check3
```

Comment: Are you viewing this in a web browser?

Comment: testing env? where did you see the output? if you are using any web browser, you should use html tag <br> for new line.

echo "next line check3<br>";

Comment: yes. viewing in web browser. so \n and PHP_EOL need to use only in CLI?

Comment: Or when writing to a file, or for readability via a "view source" in HTML, etc.... but when testing output in a web browser, __always__ use the browser's "view source"

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I think you can use this: `<br/>`